# Probably of choosing 2 numbers between 0-10000 correcctly

Tags: probability, statistics

A player can choose numbers between 0000-9999, which means there are 10,000 numbers to choose from.

The probability of choosing correctly one number is 1/10000.

So the player picks three different numbers and the game picks three different numbers, what is the probability that two of them match without regard to order?

The numbers are not repeated.

Comment: Almost. Can you see why there are 3 ways to choose exactly 2 numbers correctly?

Comment: You have to define the process carefully.  Does the player pick three different numbers and the game pick three different numbers (like in most lotteries) and we ask the chance that two of them match without regard to order?  It could be  the player picks three numbers in order, which could be duplicated, and the game picks three numbers in order, which could be duplicated.  Does it matter if the player's first guess matches the games third number drawn?  The answers depend strongly on what the question is.

Comment: In addition, does choosing 2 out of 3 mean at least 2 or exactly 2?

Comment: The probability is $\binom{1}{n-3}\binom{2}{3}$ over $\binom{3}{n}$ combinations.

You find your value by substituting $n$ with $10000$

But i don't see what does mean *3 numbers are drawn each day* ? does anyday's choice affect the other day's one ? if is the case, there should be consideration of some mutual-exclusion rule.

Comment: Also like @ross have said, do you include the case where $3$ numbers are all matched ?

Comment: Thanks, and apologies have edited to help make the question clearer!

Comment: So the player picks three different numbers and the game picks three different numbers, what is the probability that two of them match without regard to order?

Comment: Still isn't clear if the case of all three numbers match is included or not. Please edit again your question.

Comment: Thanks I just amended. There are not repeated numbers. So once a number is drawn it cant be drawn again

Comment: @Frankie139, the player should guess exactly two numbers or at least two numbers? Anyway my answer cover both the cases. Check if it's what you want or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have these possibilities of picking two correct numbers out of three: CCW, CWC and WCC where C denotes the event of choosing a number correctly and W denotes the event of choosing a number incorrectly.

The probability of this happening then is $$3\cdot\frac{1}{10000}\frac{1}{10000}\frac{9999}{10000}.$$

Comment: This is correct if the player guesses.a number, the game picks a number and we only award a win if they match, then we discard those numbers and pick some more.  Contrast this with a lottery where the player and the game each pick three numbers without replacement but there is no order to the picks.  OP has not specified the question well enough to know.

Comment: true, i see what you mean. granted there's a bit of an assumption on my part that the op has the setup in the former case you alluded to but i guess we will find out if the op adds more to the question.

Comment: Sorry have edited the question:

So the player picks three different numbers and the game picks three different numbers, what is the probability that two of them match without regard to order?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your scenario is:

- A player picks 3 numbers without replacement.
- The game picks 3 numbers without replacement (obviously from the whole set).
- The player win if he/she has picked at least 2 of 3 numbers right.

So the winning scenarios are $CCW$, $CWC$, $WCC$, $CCC$ where $C$ stands for *correct* and $W$ stands for *wrong*.

---

#### $CCW$, $CWC$, $WCC$

In the first scenario you have to take the first one correct ($\frac{3}{10000}$), the second one correct ($\frac{2}{9999}$) and the third one wrong ($\frac{9997}{9998}$).

In the second scenario you have to take the first one correct ($\frac{3}{10000}$), the second one wrong ($\frac{9997}{9999}$) and the third one correct ($\frac{2}{9998}$).

In the third scenario you have to take the first one wrong ($\frac{9997}{10000}$), the second one correct ($\frac{3}{9999}$) and the third one correct ($\frac{2}{9998}$).

As you can see, when you multiply, they have all the same value, that is $\frac{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 9997}{9998 \cdot 9999 \cdot 10000}$. You could semplify and sum up the three cases and obtain $\frac{9997}{1111 \cdot 5000 \cdot 9998}$.

#### $CCC$

In the fourth scenario you have to take the first one correct ($\frac{3}{10000}$), the second one correct ($\frac{2}{9999}$) and the third one correct ($\frac{1}{9998}$) so its probability is $\frac{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{9998 \cdot 9999 \cdot 10000}$

---

If my scenario is correct you should add the two probability, if your scenario is simply $CCW$, $CWC$, $WCC$ then don't add the $CCC$ part.